# How can I find out what Wordpress theme was used on a site, which is only available via waybackmachine aka web archive?

Tags: wordpress, themes

I've looked in the code, where one would normally find a mention of theme used, but no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Open your developer tools on the actual wayback machine archive page and search for the style.css file. At the top you should see details of the theme in the format:

```
/*
Theme Name:     Ma.tt
Theme URI:      http://ma.tt
Description:    A tribute to Mark Rothko.
Author:         Joen Asmussen
Author URI:     http://ma.tt
Template:       twentythirteen
Version:        1.0.1
*/
```

Comment: Thanks Sean, this exactly did the job for me! For me precisely: web.archive -> open latest relevant archived version of my WP page -> Firefox: F12 -> in "Style Editor" tab -> style.css